# Fatal error on startup of C# application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2010

C# Visual Studio 2010 Express:

When my application starts up, even before showing my GUI, I get following error in a dialog box:

***Fatal Problem: Value cannot be null.

Parameter name: source***

This seems to be related to some user settings in the application.
I changed a setting type from String in StringCollection, but I am not sure this is the root cause. The name "source" does not ring a bell either.

Problem is that I cannot break the application to debug this error.
When I click OK, the application starts up, but the settings are all empty for some reason.

Thanks for your help

Davy

Comment: The name "source" might have something to do with LINQ. At least that's what I've experienced. Have you tried debugging?

Comment: that error is usually related to doing operations on a collection - ie `.ToList()` on a collection which is null. It's normally the underlying LINQ translations. dont know if that helps.

Comment: Try setting up your debugger to break when any exception is thrown, then post the stacktrace of the relevant exception.

Comment: Couple of ideas here (possible duplicate?) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244336/value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-source

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to solve this is to use the debugger to find out where the exception is acutally coming from.  To do this try the following

Disable Just My Code

- Tools -> Options -> Debugger
- Uncheck "Enable Just My Code"

Turn on first chance excepions

- Debug -> Exceptions
- Check "Thrown" for "Common Language Runtime Exceptions"

Then hit F5 to start debugging your application.  This should give you a very good idea where the error is occuring and why.

Comment: I always get a "Whoah. That's cool." when I tell people about that feature. :)

Comment: I applied this and now get a "File not found exception": "Could not load file or assembly 'System.XmlSerializers, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: Then it breaks on a line with following content: "return ((global::System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection)(this["SrcPathList"]));"

Comment: In file "Settings.Designer.cs"

Comment: @Davy, that one can be ignored. (https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=88566&wa=wsignin1.0).

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**:

I replaced following code, which loads my internal *SrcPathList* from the properties:

```
*SrcPathList = new List(Properties.Settings.Default.SrcPathList.Cast()); // From StringCollection to List*
```

With this:

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.SrcPathList != null)
{
  SrcPathList = new List(Properties.Settings.Default.SrcPathList.Cast()); // From StringCollection to List
}
else
{
  SrcPathList = new List();
}
```

This solved the problem which was caused by loading an empty list causing a null value

Thank you all for your fast help!

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the setting to [break on all exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), instead of just unhandled ones.

Execution will stop right at the point where the exception is thrown, instead of at the dialog.

You're unlikely to be in the midst of your code, but you can look at the stack trace to work out what's going on.