# using expression blend with .NET micro framework

Tags: c#, wpf, expression-blend, .net-micro-framework

I just started an internship at a smaller software company here in Italy and I have been assigned
 to try and develop/create a piece of software in netmf like a timestamp machine for employees,
 which can be used on a gadgeteere board(hydra) with a 3,5in screen and a smartcard reader.

My "boss" asked me to design the GUI with pro expression blend, so far that was not to difficult,
 but now I'm stuck since I see no way of transfering the blend project to the netmf.
 I tried looking for books, but there are so few out there and those that you find are mostly about
 the netmf 3.0!

So could someone please help me, give me an idea or point me the right direction??
 I would really appreciate your help and will gladfully supply more info if needed.

Thanks
Matt

Comment: I sadly expect the answer is simply "no, Blend isn't going to output that to NetMF" - so it may have to serve as a visual prototype only

Comment: got that, but is there no way around/or thru visual studio? since I have no Idea and info how to create a sketchflow-like application with NetMF

Answer (score 0):

What about just creating a new .net mf project in VS2010 and inserting the existing xaml files in it ?? What's bad with that solution ? Because i'm afraid Blend targets only 3.5 and 4.0.

Edit : How do you do create new project ??? Well create a new project, name it save it, choose the assembly name and the namespace in the project main settings, change target Framework, then use Add existing item, then browse to add all your xaml/code/... files...

Comment: if it works, sure! just how do I do it, like I said I have been trying to find a book on this topic for a while now. Plus my C# is still pretty basic since I'm coming from Java

Comment: another things is, that from what I know NetMF does not support XAML....or is that only for 3.0?

Comment: srry, not a new project! that I can use the xaml files in the NetMF! I allready inserted the files before I asked this question...but there is no way of using them. Only the "filename.xaml.cs" and thats not all that I need. This is driving me crazy

Comment: So when you choose 'add item', you change the file filter to be able to see xaml file, then you select one of your xaml file, click 'ok' and then... what happens ??

Comment: Like I said I added the files allready before I posted this question, but they are not usable in the NetMF...so I am hoping if there is a working way to implemente them in a NetMF-project so they work. If I click on a XAML-file i get a "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: typeName"-Error

Comment: So you should search around that error, like here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244336/value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-source  from that post, it seems that a bad data initialisation is the reason for the error.

Comment: I talked to my boss for a bit and we decided to use Glide instead, simpler but faster then solving the above problem. Thanks Vincent, didnt think I would find some help that fast, really appreciated that. Until next time :)

Comment: well do not get rid of your work because of a missing data initilisation... You had some design time data right ? try to remove the references to that : most probably you have a d:DataContext searching for design time data, which are defined in the application.xaml (in the Resources) or in the resources of the Window. And it seems that vs2010 does not handle that data the same way Blend does. Blend declare and creates an instance automatically of the declared data resource, if i remember well, because it assumes that you will be using Design time data. Choose wisely :-)