# How should I handler bool? in expression

Tags: c#, linq

I write a Linq-To-Sql syntax is like below:

```
decimal? sum = UnitOfWork.MorderlistRepository.Select(
    c => c.material_id == Id && c.docstatus_id == 2 && c.is_aborted!=true && c.is_freezed!=true
).Sum(s => s.Qty);
```

the `Select` function defined as follow:

```
public virtual List<BusinessEntityT> Select(Expression<Func<TEFEntity, bool>> expression)
{
    List<BusinessEntityT> bEntities = new List<BusinessEntityT>();
    List<TEFEntity> entities = null;
    entities = _dbSet.Where(expression).ToList();
    foreach (TEFEntity entity in entities)
    {
        BusinessEntityT businessEntity = new BusinessEntityT();
        businessEntity.Context = _db;
        businessEntity.DbInstance = entity;
        bEntities.Add(businessEntity);
    }
    return bEntities;
}
```

The type of `material_id` and `docstatus_id` is `int?`, `is_aborted` and `is_freezed` is `bool?`.

Now each time when excute to the code

```
entities = _dbSet.Where(expression).ToList();
```

I always receive error message

> value can't be null,ParamName = 'source'

Why?

Comment: You could convert it to `DBNull.Value` if the `bool?` value is null.

Comment: did you verify if _dbSet is not null?

Comment: Possibly related [to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281133/value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-source).

Comment: @Viru, thanks, _dbSet is null, I'm sorry

Comment: `value can't be null,ParamName = 'source'` is a common Linq error that occurs when you try to call an extension method on a null value - in your case, `_dbSet`.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage nullable bool easilly in Linq expression usint the null coalescing operator :

```
x=> (x.myNullableBool ?? false) == false
```

The same logic an be applied ot int?

```
x=> (x.myNullableInt ?? -1) == 2
```