# Outlook REST API error when filtering by attendee: "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source"

Tags: odata, office365api, office365-restapi

I'm trying to list events using the [Outlook Calendar REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations) of an Office 365 mailbox.

Here's my request for getting all the events in 2016 that *user@example.org* attends:

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendarview/?startdatetime=2016-01-01T00:00:00Z&enddatetime=2017-01-01T00:00:00Z&$filter=Attendees/any(a: a/EmailAddress/Address eq 'user@example.org')
```

This server responds with the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInternalServerError",
        "message": "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source"
    }
}
```

From what I can tell, this really is [an internal error on their servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281133/value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-source).

When I omit the *$filter* parameter or use a simpler one instead (such as *Subject eq 'test'*) I get a valid response, so I'm guessing it has something to do with the *any* operator.

Is there another way to filter events by attendee, or a workaround for this?

Comment: Oh, hi Dor :) Have you found a solution to this problem? For me I get a valid response, even on a complex query, when the result set is empty. When there should be an item contained in the result I get the 500 with the same error as you describe here.

Comment: Hi Rotem! What are the odds :) Unfortunately I haven't got back to this. If I remember correctly I also got a valid, empty response for an empty set so I guess nothing has changed.

Comment: @RotemHarel Come to think about it, shouldn't you be the one to find a solution, given your current employment status ;)

Comment: Yes, definitely. At least to find a person who will find a solution, which I did, but at the same time was looking for either work arounds or mistakes in the way I'm using it.

Comment: @RotemHarel So did you find someone? What did they say?