# Property containing subset of related object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have entity `Post`, which is in one-to-many relationship with `Comment`. I'd like to have property which only returns certain subset of them:

```
public class Post
{

    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> TopLevelComments
    {
        get
        {
            return Comments.Where(c => c.ParentID == null).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

However, this code throws

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16281298/5153223]) seems to suggest that that's because I filter `Comments` while it's still `null`. However, in action using this method, I do eagerly load it:

```
var post = await _context.Post.Include(m => m.Author).Include(m => m.Comments).ThenInclude(m => m.Author).SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.PostID == id);
```

How can I get this to work? Is this even correct approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, to avoid this kind of exception you need to initialize your collection properties in an empty entity's constructor:

```
public Post()
{
  Comment=new List<Comment>();
}
```

Second thing is the use of `ThenInclude` suggest me you are using EF Core. If that is the case you must use eager loading because this version of EF doesn't support lazy loading.

And third thing is `TopLevelComments` property should be not mapped as part of your model:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
                .Ignore(b => b.TopLevelComments);
```