# EF CodeFrist to existing Db

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I want learn EF 6 CodeFirst to an Existing Database (SQLServer)

When I trying to run my project i got this error:

**Exception**

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   source

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var meetings = db.Meetings
        .OrderBy(e => e.StartDate)
        .Where(e => e.IsPublic)
        .Select(e => new MeetingViewModel()
            {
                MeetingId = e.MeetingId,
                MeetingName = e.MeetingName,
                MeetingTypeName = e.MeetingType.Name,
                LocationName = e.MeetingLocation.Name,
                StartDate = e.StartDate,
            });

    var upcomingMeetings = meetings.Where(e => e.StartDate > DateTime.Now);
    var passedMeetings = meetings.Where(e => e.StartDate <= DateTime.Now);
    return View(HomeIndex, new HomePageModel());
}
```

**Page Model**

```
public class HomePageModel
{
    public IEnumerable<MeetingViewModel> UpcommingMeetings { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MeetingViewModel> PassedMeetings { get; set; }
}
```

**Cshtml**

```
@model AquaEvent.Common.HomePageModel
<div class="row">
    @if (Model.UpcommingMeetings.Any())
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.UpcommingMeetings)
    }
</div>
```

connectioString is EF AutoGenerator without changing

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the error?

Comment: How about assigning `upcomingMeetings` and `passedMeetings` to the `new HomePageModel()` properties.

Comment: Please refer this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281133/value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-source

Comment: Provide your connection string

Comment: @IvanStoev Yeah I'm missing that, Thank you And dear Rainman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing the collections in the model and `UpcommingMeetings` causes null exception error in the view;

```
var upcomingMeetings = meetings.Where(e => e.StartDate > DateTime.Now);
var passedMeetings = meetings.Where(e => e.StartDate <= DateTime.Now);
return View(HomeIndex, new HomePageModel()
{
    UpcommingMeetings = upcomingMeetings,
    PassedMeetings = passedMeetings
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I lost 5h of my time for this, I looking for a error in my Db migration. because all of similar quiz linked me to it. Thank you!