# throw Value cannot be null just in producttion - EF core

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I am using `EF Core  v 1.2`  , In my project I have a method when I debug it or when I run it in local machine It works fine and return data , but when I publish project in production mode it returns an exception :

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: source  , {State:l}

Exactly this code without any changes work properly .

**Note** : the Code executed form an background Service .

Comment: Can you check the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281133/value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-source. Maybe your code has .Any(), .ToList(), ... and the value before . is null

Comment: As I mentioned, I works fine in loca machine with exact same DataBase , just when I run Background job On server it throw this exception