# Converted EF 6 WPF application to EF Core, getting null exception from what was a working query

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

First off, I would probably still class myself as a novice in EF. Done some code first migrations but only simple things.

Anyway, I have a WPF app I made which is using EF 6. I am now having a look at .Net Core 3 and decided to have a go at converting the app.

Generating the database models I used scaffolding.

Ok so the problem. 
In the current app running EF6 this code works fine.

```
            var items2 = DbContext.UutResult.Where(x =>
                x.StartDateTime != null && (x.StartDateTime.Value.Date >= startDate &&
                                            x.StartDateTime.Value.Date <= endDate &&
                                            x.StationId == testerId)).Select(x => new TestResultItem()
            {
                TesterId = (int) x.TestSocketIndex,
                TesterType = x.StationId,
                TestDateTime = (DateTime) x.StartDateTime,
                TestResult = x.UutStatus,
                PanelBarcode = x.BatchSerialNumber,
                UutBarcode = x.UutStatus,
                TestTimeSec = (double) x.ExecutionTime,
                TestSteps = x.StepResult.Where(y => y.StepGroup == "Main").Select(y => new TestResultStepItem()
                {
                    StepName = y.StepName,
                    Report = y.ReportText,
                    TestResult = y.Status,
                    UpperLimit = y.StepNumericlimit1.FirstOrDefault().StepNumericlimit2.FirstOrDefault().HighLimit.ToString(),
                    OrderId = (int)y.OrderNumber
                }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

But running the same in EF core I get the following error.

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   source'

Stack Trace

> at System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetFirst[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Boolean& found)
>      at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext , TransparentIdentifier`2 )
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.ProjectionShaper.TypedProjectionShaper`3.Shape(QueryContext queryContext, ValueBuffer& valueBuffer)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.ProjectionShaper.TypedProjectionShaper`3.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.IShaper.Shape(QueryContext queryContext, ValueBuffer& valueBuffer)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryBuffer.CorrelateSubquery[TInner,TOut,TCollection](Int32 correlatedCollectionId, INavigation navigation, Func`2 resultCollectionFactory, MaterializedAnonymousObject& outerKey, Boolean tracking, Func`1 correlatedCollectionFactory, Func`3 correlationPredicate)
>      at lambda_method(Closure , ValueBuffer )
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at EPQT.ServiceLayer.TesterService.GetTestData(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, String testerId, String productFilter) in C:\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Extractor\Core\EPQT.ServiceLayer\TesterService.cs:line 120
>      at EPQT.Modules.TesterQuery.Views.TestQueryViewModel.<>c__DisplayClass54_0.b__0() in C:\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Extractor\Modules\EPQT.Modules.TesterQuery\Views\TestQueryViewModel.cs:line 218
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__277_0(Object obj)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)

So I narrowed down the issue to this line.

```
UpperLimit = y.StepNumericlimit1.FirstOrDefault().StepNumericlimit2.FirstOrDefault().HighLimit.ToString(),
```

So `y` potentially has many children called `StepNumericlimit1` and that potentially has many children called `StepNumericlimit2`.

Basically I am trying to say if `y` has any `StepNumericlimit1` children then grab the first one. Then, if there is a child found, check to see if that has any `StepNumericlimit2` children. If it does, then grab the property `Data` from the first child.

Not sure if it's how EF core handles this or the way it has genereated the code or maybe even my query it written poorly... or maybe all the above lol

**UPDATE:** Some EF generated code, deleted irrelevant code.

```
public partial class StepResult
{
    public StepResult()
    {
        StepNumericlimit1 = new HashSet<StepNumericlimit1>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? UutResult { get; set; }
    public virtual UutResult UutResultNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StepNumericlimit1> StepNumericlimit1 { get; set; }
}

public partial class StepNumericlimit1
{
    public StepNumericlimit1()
    {
        StepNumericlimit2 = new HashSet<StepNumericlimit2>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? StepResult { get; set; }
    public double? Data { get; set; }

    public virtual StepResult StepResultNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StepNumericlimit2> StepNumericlimit2 { get; set; }
}

public partial class StepNumericlimit2
{
    public Guid? PropResult { get; set; }
    public double? HighLimit { get; set; }
    public double? LowLimit { get; set; }

    public virtual StepNumericlimit1 PropResultNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

OnModelCreating

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<StepNumericlimit1>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("STEP_NUMERICLIMIT1");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.StepResult)
                .HasName("StepResultIndex");

            entity.Property(e => e.StepResult).HasColumnName("STEP_RESULT");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.StepResultNavigation)
                .WithMany(p => p.StepNumericlimit1)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.StepResult)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                .HasConstraintName("STEP_NUMERICLIMIT1_STEP_RESULT_FK");
        });

modelBuilder.Entity<StepNumericlimit2>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("STEP_NUMERICLIMIT2");  

            entity.Property(e => e.HighLimit).HasColumnName("HIGH_LIMIT");

            entity.Property(e => e.LowLimit).HasColumnName("LOW_LIMIT");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.PropResultNavigation)
                .WithMany(p => p.StepNumericlimit2)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.PropResult)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                .HasConstraintName("STEP_NUMERICLIMIT2_STEP_NUMERICLIMIT1_FK");
        });
```

**UPDATE 2:**
So in order to provide more information I was aiming to create a new project and database with dummy data, but very minamal i.e. stripping out tables not required and columns not related to the query.

I did this and now the query works fine, even with NULL child properties. I have checked the generated code from scafolding in both projects and they are the same.

So how can I find what the issue is?

Comment: Check your connection string, might be that it is not defined or not properly and in addition, have a look at some of these answers and see if one can help=> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281133/value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-source

Comment: I know its not the string because I can run other less complicated querys fine. Plus, if i comment out that one line I identified as the issue, it runs fine aswell.

Comment: Editted, have a look at the url, check your object y and its (referenced)properties to see if any of them are NULL.

Comment: In Ef core you need to use Include() function to retrieve related data ( children ) before where() function  DbContext.UutResult.Include(... )

Comment: I already had a look at that link. Didn't really help. 
I am assuming property is NULL because of the error. Question is how do i handle this? EF 6 did this for me, i assume as it didn't give me the exception.

Comment: @AlaaeddineHFIDHI oh really? ok I will try this now, thank you.

Comment: @AlaaeddineHFIDHI is right, EF Core (opposed to EF 6) does not load related objects automatically (no lazy-loading)

Comment: There is [many other things that works different](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/) in EF 6 and EF Core

Answer (score 1):

This solution should be work fine !!

```
var items2 = DbContext.UutResult.Include(r=>r.StepNumericlimit1).ThenInclude(r=>r.StepNumericlimit2).Where(x =>
                x.StartDateTime != null && (x.StartDateTime.Value.Date >= startDate &&
                                            x.StartDateTime.Value.Date <= endDate &&
                                            x.StationId == testerId)).Select(x => new TestResultItem()
            {
                TesterId = (int) x.TestSocketIndex,
                TesterType = x.StationId,
                TestDateTime = (DateTime) x.StartDateTime,
                TestResult = x.UutStatus,
                PanelBarcode = x.BatchSerialNumber,
                UutBarcode = x.UutStatus,
                TestTimeSec = (double) x.ExecutionTime,
                TestSteps = x.StepResult.Where(y => y.StepGroup == "Main").Select(y => new TestResultStepItem()
                {
                    StepName = y.StepName,
                    Report = y.ReportText,
                    TestResult = y.Status,
                    UpperLimit = y.StepNumericlimit1.FirstOrDefault().StepNumericlimit2.FirstOrDefault().HighLimit.ToString(),
                    OrderId = (int)y.OrderNumber
                }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

For more informations, I invite you to read this documentation 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/read-related-data?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: doesn't  seem to work. I took your query, modified the top line to read line this.

"DbContext.UutResult.Include(x => x.StepResult).ThenInclude(x => x.StepNumericlimit1).ThenInclude(x => x.StepNumericlimit2).Where("

But still the error.

Comment: can you give me the database schema ?

Comment: It's a business database so I am limited to what I can provide. Whats is it you are looking for and I might be able to help.

Comment: i Need to see the realtion between concerned tables to be able to resolve this issue

Comment: I will add some EF generated code, stripping out none esstentiall properties.