# Untracked Exception: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: headers

Tags: c#, entity-framework, web-services, wcf

**Problem**

There's WCF connected to Silverlight. When it's time for the service to return `args`, it returns an `error` with the exception and no actual result that it should return.

**Exception**

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: headers
```

There's no parameter named headers. I put emphasis on not having a field named headers in the model which the service returns.

**Possible Solution which didn't work out**

- Checked every `Any()`, `Where` and `Count()` not used when it's null
- Checked `{get;}` doesn't exist except when it's with `set;`
- Traced whole of code and it didn't have any exception or null value
- Checked whole of code to be in different `try-catches`
- Checked `Web.config` and all of connection strings are right; .
- I updated the service multiple times and checked its configuration
- I couldn't remove `defining query` I wasn't allowed to

**Stack Trace**

```cs
   at System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.ChannelBase`1.EndInvoke(String methodName, Object[] args, IAsyncResult result)
   at UIE.SrvE.SrvEClient.SrvEClientChannel.EndGetSubmit(IAsyncResult result)
   at UIE.SrvE.SrvEClient.UIE.SrvEngineer.ISrvE.EndGetSubmit(IAsyncResult result)
   at UIE.SrvE.SrvEClient.OnEndGetSubmit(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.OnAsyncCallCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
```

There are so many questions about this exception like this one [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281133/value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-source) but none of them is about headers.

Please, suggest to me any possible solutions.

Comment: Can you show me the entity you are trying to fetch from your database?

Comment: @THEoneANDonly Everything comes back from database perfectly. I've checked it based of database's content.

Comment: If you can get the data from the database, it means that ef is fine, but the wcf service has an error connecting to Silverlight, maybe Silverlight has a problem.