# How to resolve error: "value cannot be null parameter name Response" in Linq?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

Getting this error

> Value cannot be null.
> Parameter name : response

in LINQ while executing the statements shown here. Please let me know. Error is not occurring if I comment out the filterItem statement. Below changes are working fine in local but on deployed server getting the above error.

```cs
[HttpGet]
[LingToQuerable]
public dynamic Get(){

   var query = Request.GetQueryString();

   var countRes = db.Employees
      .Include(emp => emp.applicationusr)
      .Include(x => x.applicationuser.Roles)
      .AsQuerable()
      .LinqToQuerystring<Employee,Dictionary<string,object>>(query);

   IQueryable<Employee> list;
   count = (int)countRes["Count"];
   list = countResult["Results"] as IQuerable<Employee>;
   var filterItem = 
      from employee in list
      select new ListOfEmpDTO
      {
         id = employee.id.
         status = employee. status,
      }
   var results = filterItem.ToList();

   return new FilterModelDTO<ListOfEmpDTO>
   { 
      items = resultes.Distinct(), 
      Counts = count
   }
}
```

Comment: Taken a Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16281133/7450780)?

Comment: There's a lot of things fundamentally wrong with the code snippet you provided. First of all, there is no `response` anywhere in the code so it has nothing to do with the error. Second, the variable `list` is not the generic `IQueryable<T>` so you can't do linq operations on it. Thirdly, even if you were able to use linq, since there is no known type for your entities, you cannot access properties off them, they are all `object`. Please add more details if you'd like us to be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Added more code details above. Please help.

Comment: I removed [LingToQuerable] attribute and moved entire code under using (db = new DBContextName) and then i got error "there is already an open datareader associated with this command which must be closed first" . Then i added MultipleActiveResultSets=True; to the connections string. Then it started working.

Comment: Please correct your code, looks like it is non compilable and local variables are in mess.

Comment: Also what is `LinqToQuerystring`? Post exception call stack, usually it has answer what you have did wrong.