# C# : Cannot create razor page using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, razor-pages

I created an ASP.NET Core 6 Razor pages project in Visual Studio 2022 and when I tried to create a razor page using Entity Framework (CRUD) in the Add new scaffolded item section, I get this error:

> value cannot be null
> parameter name: unconfiguredProjectCommonServices

I installed the following packages in my project:

1. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design (6.0.27)
2. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLServer (6.0.27)
3. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration (6.0.16)
4. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (6.0.27)
5. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools (6.0.27)

I've found nothing about this specific error so far, what is this error and how can I fix this ? Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools packages.

Comment: Here's a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281133/value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-source) and you might check it. By the way, the error message points to a parameter named `unconfiguredProjectCommonServices`, you might search for it in your project and see if the issue would disappear after commenting related lines.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by installing .NET 6.0 WebAssembly Build Tools.