# Getting exception when inserting an entity into a EF table

Tags: entity-framework

I get the following `ArgumentNullException` when I insert a rather simple entity into a table.
I don't think it matters, but the database is an SQL Server Compact .sdf file.

> **Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: source**
>
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.WrapUpdateException(UpdateException updateException)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
>   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
>   {{ the code below }}

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
var newMaterial = _localJobs.DbMaterials.Create();

newMaterial.JobID = a_job.ID;
newMaterial.MaterialName = material.Name;
newMaterial.UseType = material.UseType;
newMaterial.Length = material.Length;
newMaterial.Width = material.Width;
newMaterial.Thickness = material.Thickness;
newMaterial.DefaultLength = material.DefaultLength;
newMaterial.DefaultWidth = material.DefaultWidth;
newMaterial.DefaultThickness = material.DefaultThickness;

_localJobs.DbMaterials.Add(newMaterial);
_localJobs.SaveChanges(); // <- The exception occurs here.
```

I am properly populating every field with valid data. The only key herein is `JobID`. It is a foreign key GUID with an explicit relation with a table called `Job`. The proper record already exists in the database.

Here is my table schema.

[image]

Comment: When you debug, do all of the other fields have non-null values?

Comment: This might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244336/using-linq-to-find-item-in-a-list-but-get-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name - Might not though. Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281133/value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-source

Comment: What does the Material class look like?

Comment: Material class is a simple POCO where `Name` is a string; `UseType` is a string; `Length`, `Width`, and `Thickness` are doubles; and `DefaultLength`, `DefaultWidth`, and `DefaultThickness` are doubles. None of these are nullable and all are set to valid values when I debug.

Comment: Sorry, I meant DbMaterials. I vaguely remember a similar error if you use fields in your `Context` class, rather than properties. E.g. if you had `public DbSet<Material> DbMaterials ;`, you'd want `public DbSet<Material> DbMaterials { get; set; }`

Comment: I am using database first, so my entities are generated. I'm not one to use non-constant public fields anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very old thread but still I am going to post answer to it because i had similar issue and I could not find answer on it. Maybe it will help someone.

Answer for me was very silly. My ID column was not an primary key of the table.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you have a field that:

- Does not allow nulls
- Does not have a default value
- That you do not supply a value for in the insert

The reason for the error could be:

- you are setting one of the fields to null
- the save changes is also trying to save a row that was added earlier that is not showing up in the code you posted.

Try using SQL Profiler then you will see which insert statement is causing the error.

Comment: The exception is not to me. It is an exception occuring deep within Entity Framework code that is not caught. The reason for the exception is that `InternalContext.WrapUpdateException` is calling `Enumerable.Any` with a null reference in the `source` parameter. I verified that I am properly setting all of the fields to valid values. When I enter the values manually into the table, everything works just fine. So I don't think the problem is with SQL at all.

Answer (score 0):

Given you will have checked all of the sensible suggestions already provided. Then another possibility is You model and DB dont Match.

Do you have a

> Migration outstanding.

.. Double check.  I have seen this message before ;-)

Comment: My model matches perfectly. I even tried rebuilding the table from scratch. No luck.