# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source?

Tags: c#

```
private void cbNomSociete_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  dgvListeAssemblee.DataSource = (
    from x in ListAssemble
    where x.Denomination
           .ToUpper()
           .Contains( cbNomSociete.SelectedItem.ToString().ToUpper() )
    select x
    ).ToList() ;

 }
```

how can this be fixed please

Comment: This looks like a few other stack questions for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281133/value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-source OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244336/using-linq-to-find-item-in-a-list-but-get-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name

Comment: Debug it in Visual Studio. Enable the option "Break when exception is thrown" and you'll get the callstack.

Answer (score 1):

> how can this be fixed please

Figure out which variable/property is `null`.  Based on the error message, the exception is likely coming from a static Linq extension method (since they all have a first parameter named `source`), which would mean the most likely candidate is `ListAssemble`.

If `x.Denomination` or `cbNomSociete.SelectedItem` were `null` you'd see a different error message.